# How to involve audience during a solo performance?

Tags: solos

What are the ways to involve an audience during a solo performance? And what do you do if you feel they are not interested in listening?

Comment: Would this be solo drums, vocal, piano, etc. There are some important details that need adding into your question.  What sort of audience - seated, dancing, 20 people, 1000 people? What sort of venue? Karaoke, pub, stadium, someone's lounge? All salient points missing!  Maybe your profile is a clue, maybe not...

Comment: If they're not interested, then either (1) they didn't know what kind of music was on the program, (2) your performance is weak, (3) it's just one of those days.  Ask any standup comic: sometimes you bomb; get used to it and prepare for a better night next time.

Comment: Sorry, but without extra information, I will vote to close this question as it cannot be understood what is being asked.

Answer (score 4):

- Talk to them.
- Tell some jokes.
- Give them some anecdotes referring to the song sung.
- Choose an audience member, and talk diectly to them.
- Be self- deprecating.
- Make eye contact with some members of the audience.
- Do not stick to a set list - choose various different styles/songs to suit        what you think they may appreciate.
- Try segueing several songs.
- Stop playing at some point, and ask them what they would like - you may not get constructive answers, but at least you'll know!
- If all else fails, find a different venue, with a different audience. It might just be the square peg in the round hole.

Comment: Be self-deprecating... you must be English!  JK, I do that plenty as well.  It certainly works for comedians, so it could easily work for a musician as well, however, I wouldn't overemphasize this aspect of things.

Comment: @Basstickler - English through and through! You wouldn't overemphasise it - I didn't . It was 10% of my answer...  If one can't take the rise out of oneself, then it's hardly fair to take it out of anyone else, and if one doesn't do it to oneself, someone else is going to do it for one...

Comment: Right, I certainly didn't think you were suggesting it should be the centerpiece of their performance banter, just thought I'd throw it out there.  My joke on being English and self-deprecation basically comes from John Oliver jokes.

Answer (score 0):

Perform well, to an audience interested in your type of music.  Or, sometimes, accept that you're just background, they quite like the noise you're making but also want to drink, talk etc.  Just carry on, and don't try to force attention by turning up louder!   You got the gig, which suggests you may be doing what the management requires.

Oh, and don't take prolonged jazz solos, unless you're a guitarist playing to a guitar club.  Even then, don't kid yourself.  They're just pretending interest until it's THEIR turn.